# Strange Google Play Batch IAP API Error

Tags: android, json, in-app-purchase, google-play-developer-api

According to the documentation for the [Google Play Developer API](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/inappproducts/batch), I should be able to batch insert or update requests. However, I’m running into an issue where it appears that either the documentation is wrong, the API is broken, or I’m just missing something.

I’m `POST`ing to the URL: `https://www.googleapis.com/androidpublisher/v2/applications/inappproducts/batch?access_token=<my token here>&autoConvertMissingPrices=true'
My`Content-Type`is set to:`application/json
`And the body of my`POST` is the following:

```
{
    "entrys": [{
        "batchId": "<my batch id>",
        "methodName": "update",
        "inappproductsupdaterequest": {
            "inappproduct": {
                "packageName": "<my package name>",
                "sku": "<my product sku>",
                "status": "active",
                "purchaseType": "managedUser",
                "defaultPrice": {
                    "priceMicros": "<my price>",
                    "currency": "USD"
                },
                "listings": {
                    "en-US": {
                        "title": "<my title> ",
                        "description": "<my description>"
                    }
                },
                "defaultLanguage": "en-US"
            }
        }
    }]
}
```

When I `POST` this, I get the following error:

```
{
    "error": {
        "errors": [
            {
                "domain": "global",
                "reason": "required",
                "message": "Required parameter: [entry[0].inappproductsUpdateRequest.package_name]",
                "locationType": "parameter",
                "location": "[entry[0].inappproductsUpdateRequest.package_name]"
            }
        ],
        "code": 400,
        "message": "Required parameter: [entry[0].inappproductsUpdateRequest.package_name]"
    }
}
```

If I’m reading this correctly, they want the package name parameter as a child element under `inappproductsUpdateRequest`. However, when I try moving or copying (tried both) `"packageName": "<my package name>"` as a child under `inappproductsUpdateRequest`, I get the error:

```
{
    "error": {
        "errors": [
            {
                "domain": "global",
                "reason": "invalid",
                "message": "Unknown field name: packageName",
                "locationType": "other",
                "location": "entrys.inappproductsupdaterequest"
            }
        ],
        "code": 400,
        "message": "Unknown field name: packageName"
    }
}
```

I get the same error when I try `package_name` instead of `packageName`.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the requested casing `inappproductsUpdateRequest` that the response shows? I'm guessing you do need snake case on `package_name` rather than `packageName`, but you may need to try both there too.

Comment: changing the casing to `inappproductsUpdateRequest` just gives an error: `"Unknown field name: inappproductsUpdateRequest"`